# For which values of $a$ is $f(x) = \cos(ax)$ a contraction mapping?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

I am studying contraction mapping and got stuck on this question:

> Consider the following function:
>
> $$f(x)=\cos(ax),\ a,x \in \mathbb{R}.$$
>
> Find values of $a$ for which $f$ is a contraction mapping.

Any help with this question is hugely appreciated.

Comment: Recall that the absolute value of the derivative can be useful in such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is a contracting map if $\exists \alpha \in (0,1): \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}, |f(x)-f(y)|< \alpha|x-y|.$

Let's evaluate the following expression for any x,y: $|f(x)-f(y)|=|\cos(ax)-\cos(ay)|$.

Let's note that since $f$ is differentiable, then according to Lagrange's theorem, we can write:

$$\exists c\in (x,y): |f(x)-f(y)|=\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}|x-y|=|f'(c)||x-y|=|-a\sin(ac)||x-y|.$$

Since we want $f$ to be a contracting map, then we want this expression to be less than $ \alpha|x-y| $ for some $ \alpha \in (0,1)$.

Therefore, we want the following:

$$\exists \alpha \in (0,1): |-a\sin(ac)||x-y|< \alpha |x-y|.$$

Let's note that $|\sin(ac)|\leq 1$, and therefore, $|-a\sin(ac)||x-y|\leq |-a||x-y|=|a||x-y|$.

Therefore, we want $|a|\in (0,1)$, in order to ensure that $\exists \alpha \in (0,1): |a||x-y|<\alpha |x-y|$.

Comment: The map is also a contraction when $a = 0$.

Comment: thank you for that! 

how would I do a contraction mapping proof? 

|sin b - sin a|<_ |b-a| 

i need to prove that for all a,b E R that the above statement is true. 

could i use the mean value theorem for this? which kind of proof technique could i use?